# How to convert String which is there in specific format to Integer

Tags: java

I have String which I want to convert into Integer.

example -   I have string in below format

Input :   `ABCD00000123`

Output: `123`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8):

```
// First remove all non number characters from String 
input= input.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );  
// Convert it to int
int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

For example

```
input = "ABCD00000123";
```

After

```
input= input.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );
```

input will be "00000123"

```
 int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

`int` will be 123.

This is one of the simple solution if the input is always in the format mentioned in the question. There can be multiple scenarios considering position of numeric characters with respect to non numberic characters  like
0123ABC
0123ABC456
ABC0123DE

Comment: This is a good answer, but as a note: `input = "A3B32BDC2";` will yield 3322 as its output, which might not be desired.

Comment: @SteveP.: Thanks. Was about to add it. Updated my answer.

Comment: Just a doubt, isn't \D the pattern for non-digit characters?, why using [^\\d]?

Comment: @Daniel: `\d` matches any single digit (equivalent to the class [0-9]). Conversely, capital `\D` means *any non-digit*. I think `\d` will be appropriate choice here.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "ABCD00000123"
int output = Integer.parseInt(s.subString(4));

System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: What about `String s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()-=_+|\{}<00000123"`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I would argue that it isn't in the format he specified, but as the question wasn't very clear, it's difficult to know exactly what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell yo the logic for it... convert this String into a character array, and then parse it from the first index (0 for array), up to length and check the first non-zero integer number, then from that location to the remaining length of the String copy this to another String and then parse it using Integer.parseInt();

```
String val = "ABCD00000123";
String arr[] = val.toCharArray();
int cnt;
for(cnt = 0 ; cnt < arr.length; cnt++){
switch(arr[cnt]){

/*Place your logic here to check the first non-zero number*/

}
}
```

and then follow the remaining logic.

if you have enough programming concepts then only you can do it...